# PHP MySQL Row level security

Tags: mysql, security, authorization

I am looking for an example or information on row level security for PHP and MySQL. I have done the basic google reasearch, I have read all the posts / articles about using views and adding fields to table to specify what user has the right to view the object. Those example are fairly simple and would require lots of configuration / maintenance.

Here are a few real life examples of what i am looking for:

Clients data, allow to configurer what user or user group can view all or parts of the client file. This must be persistent for all the application features including reports and dashboards.

Employee files, give access to immediate supervisor and HR to an employee file without having to reconfigurer the access rights when supervisors change.

I think this should be handled directly from the database layer, but could also be applied to other resources for examples, uploaded documents.

I'm hinting to some sort of "filter" that I could pass my data into so it could be filtered.

Any interesting links to articles or frameworks that have implemented this with success would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: MySQL does not natively offer security of this sort, although one *could* implement something along these lines within the database layer using sprocs: however, it's more normal to perform such access control within your application layer (it doesn't really have anything to do with how the data is structured or stored, but rather is very much to do with your business logic).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use MariaDB to do this, as MySQL doesn't do ROLEs, though you *might* be able to use GRANT PROXY to accomplish what you want in MySQL.

I think that different "tenants", i.e. paying customers, should be in different databases to avoid leakage. You can use scripting to automate this.

But if you want intra-company row-level security, you can accomplish this with an extra column per table and some views and triggers.

create a table with an owner column. Use an insert trigger to set owner to the current user. REVOKE all privileges on the table.

create a view WITH CHECK OPTION on that table that checks that *current user is in a role that matches the owner*. GRANT all privileges on the view.

Example:

```
create user `pointyHead`;
create user `dilbert`;

create role `manager`;
create role `minion`;

grant manager to pointyHead;
grant minion to dilbert;
grant minion to manager;
```

Not sure if there is a function to check if user is in role, but you can always use information_schema.applicable_roles.

You can use column-level grants to give different column permissions to different users. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html#grant-column-privileges .